Does ROS2 (Humble) support rosconsole / log4cxx?
We're currently in the process of migrating from ROS 1 (noetic) to ROS 2 (humble), whilst also modifying our logging setup. In noetic this seems to be fairly straightforward. My understanding is that rosconsole makes use of log4cxx and that this is a fairly standard and customisable logging framework.
I've been unable to find any references to rosconsole or log4cxx support for humble. Does it exist and, if not, is there a plan to support it in the future?
